# Получение ссылки для поиска в группах VK.com

Tags: link

ВКонтакте имеется поиск в группе по записям. Например, здесь я ищу посты со словом "Рок". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне получить ссылку, которая бы переводила меня на эту страницу, где в поиске уже вбито определённое слово (в данном случае "Рок") и готовы результаты этого поиска. Сверху же в адресной строке ссылка не меняется в зависимости от поиска и указывает на саму группу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://vk.com/wall-<id группы>?id=<id группы>&q=<поисковая фраза>
```

Узнать ID группы можно через исходный код, например, в названии группы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У Пикабу ID = 31480508. Поиск по всем записям пикабу с котиками будет выглядеть так:

```
https://vk.com/wall-31480508?id=31480508&q=котики
```

Comment: а как сделать если у тебя два слова в поиске?

Comment: Через пробел:
&q=влажные%20киски